# Adding a field to sales_flat_order, vs. extending with a table

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento-1.4

This is for Magento 1.4.x - I have discovered that the actual tax rate used for calculation of that order (say 8.25% for example) does not have a field to go into in `sales_flat_order` - which is pretty lame IMO considering the number of other detailed pieces of information this table and the _items table have.

I am considering extending the model and adding a `tax_rate` field to the table itself.  Another option is to extend with an EAV table and store the attribute there.  Is the former an acceptable solution, and will it survive an upgrade to version 2.0 which we are planning on doing soon?

Answer (score 1):

The tax is not calculated over the order in total, but the order items. It could be that you have 2 products in your cart/order, one with a lox taxing rate of 6% and one with a high rate of 21%. You also have shipping costs, which might be tax free, so 0%.

So in this case, there is no tax rate for the order. Extending the table as you suggest wouldn't be a solution, since it wouldn't make sense to the way the tax is calculated or split for an order.